# fastapi callback (webhook) микросервис

Tags: python, api, callback, микросервисы, fastapi

не могли бы вы подсказать, мне нужно настроить проверку статуса выполнения запроса, скажем запрос выполняется долго, и чтобы у разработчика, который обращается, не было timeout или подвисания программы во время ожидания, нужно проверять статус, работает ли программа после запроса, упала ли, а в случае выполнения возвращала бы результат выполнения.

как я понимаю это callback (вебхук). у fastapi есть описание этого [метода](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/openapi-callbacks/?h=+call), только как я понял он не так работает как мне нужно, обращаясь обратно к сервису разработчика, который сделал запрос, и ожидая от него ответ. если я всё правильно понял.

верно ли использовать метод callback в fastapi?
нужен другой метод? если ли ссылки на примеры/документацию?

можно ли проверить callback с помощью postman/insomnia?

Comment: Да просто сделайте два отдельных запроса: первый запрос ставит операцию на выполнение и сразу выходит, возвращая какой-то id операции, операция в фоне выполняется, после завершения допустим в базу пишет статус, что завершилась. Вторым запросом по id операции периодически проверяете статус.